# Can I index on a MySQL tinyInt?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, mariadb

I'm trying to make a page load very fast. To assist me in this, I would like to query a table based strictly on a boolean column.

In my case, comparatively few rows in this table will have this boolean column set as true, the rest will be false.

Can databases generally make a nice little search tree, that would say, go left if you want false, and go right if you want true, to get to the list of their respective primary keys?

Comment: you can, and it'd probably help. but as always: try it and benchmark both ways.

Comment: Also, did you make sure the SQL time was significant in your total loading time?

Comment: A database can do this, but in reality small table searches will probably just optimise to a table scan anyway. `EXPLAIN` will help you to decide the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can put an index on it.

Then you could run a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mybool = 1
AND [another condition here]
```

The added index would ensure that the second condition only runs on the records that have mybool set to 1, which would in theory make your query faster (assuming high cardinality on `mybool = 1` and a significant number of rows).

Note that proper use of indexes can improve read-speed, but it can slow down write-speed as indexes need to be updated during insert.

EDIT: As requested, to add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (mybool)
```

Comment: saved me .3 seconds. I didn't think to try index type "KEY"

Comment: And now it takes 0.008 seconds. So, quite a significant speedup.

Comment: The speed difference will greatly vary depending on your record-set, but it definitely seems worth it in your case, so for sure you can keep it.

Comment: This table is going to have millions upon millions of records. Yet just a few thousand will be marked true

Comment: Dany can you edit your answer to include the sql command to add the index? The type I used was "KEY"

Comment: I've added that part.

Comment: For technical details, read about [Index Merge Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html). Alternatively, you could have a multi-column index.